# Injecting DbContext and using one connection to Execute multiple Queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core and ASP.NET Core:

```
 public partial class SecurityDBContext : DbContext
 {
      // injecting the DBcontext from the ASP.NET or Bootstrap applicaiton with the required connection string
      public SecurityDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
      {

      }
}
```

This is my repository class where I am injecting the required context:

```
 public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private SecurityDBContext securityDb;
    private readonly ILogger<UserRepository> _logger;

    public UserRepository(SecurityDBContext securityContext, ILogger<UserRepository> logger)
    {
        securityDb = securityContext;
        _logger = logger;

    }
    public void MultipleQueries(int id)
    {

        var result1= securityDb.Users.Where(u=> u.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();


       //var result2 = securityDb.Table2.Where(...)ToList();
    }
```

And here is how i am passing the dependecies:

```
var securityDB = configurationRoot.GetConnectionString("SecurityDatabase");
if (securityDB == null)
   {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("SecurityDatabase ConnectionString");
   }
//EnityDB
    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<SecurityCore.Repositories.SecurityDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(securityDB));
```

Lets say I have result 2 and result 3 that are executed on different DB Entities, is the context opening a connection for each query? If Yes, then how I avoid that according to best practices and do my queries through one connection.

Comment: Keeping a connection open is not the best practice.

Comment: @GertArnold, Please clarify, do you mean its always open now since i am not disposing it, shouldn't the dependency injection framework manage that?

Comment: The context manages its own db connections, you shouldn't worry about that. Just use a context as long as long as you need it (standard is: during one request) and don't open and close db connections.

Comment: Do you mean that what i am doing is the ideal way, couldn't we execute multiple queries using one connection?

Comment: No, I'm saying you shouldn't worry about connections. I don't understand your question. What is your concern? What do you think you can't do when you just use the context as it is injected?

Comment: I am asking about executng multple queries using one connection, if you check the method `MutlipleQueries` where i am going to call `ToList()` or `SingleOrDefault` on different Db Entities, I assume that result2 would open another connection different from that used in result1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134533/discussion-between-h-salman-and-gert-arnold).

Comment: @h.salman: Do you have any evidence for your assumption? DbContext keeps a connection pool within and reuse it. No need to manage connections yourself. You shouldn't do any kind of preemptive optimization w/o claims that there is an issue with it!!!